# Why does javascript care if this variable is local or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, scope

Making the following call using jquery:

```
var x = $.get("/page");
```

The page sends some json data back which I want to access via x.responseJSON. If the variable is local as in the example x is undefined. If I remove the local devlaration it's fine. This is not a scope issue as it's all taking place within the same scope. I only noticed this behavior even by making the calls in the developer console which prints the returned object to the console automatically.

Comment: I'm not clear what your problem is. My guess is, however, that you're attempting to access `responseJSON` before the HTTP request is complete.

Comment: `x` should be a `jqXHR` object, and I don't see the `responseJSON` property in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined because you are not telling the console to return anything. When you do not include the `var x =`, the console displays the object.

Type the following into the console:

```
var x = "123";
```

and than type

```
x;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An ajax request is an asynchronous task, so you need to process the response in the sucess callback:

```
$.get('/page', function(x) {
    console.log(x,'marks the spot');
});
```